# How do I import a grayscale image into a 2D matrix in C?

Tags: c, image-processing, matrix, bmp, grayscale

I need to read a .bmp grayscale image into a 2D matrix. The values (int) on the matrix will be the corresponding grayscale levels on the image (from 0 to 255).

Being more specific, let´s assume I have an 8 -bit grayscale image 4x4 pixels.

I want to convert it to a 2d matrix, which values will be the grayscale levels, for example:

|0......2......4.......5 |

|10....11....12....10|

|210..200..150..98|

|1.....10....50.....88|

So far, I've managed to import the grayscale image into 3 matrix (RGB), but when I try to convert it to a single matrix (grayscale) using conversion factors, it does not work. The image became different form the original.

The conversion function i'm using is:
...

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) 
    { 
     b[i][j] = (int)(0.11*b[i][j] + 0.59*g[i][j] + 0.3*r[i][j]);
     g[i][j] = b[i][j];
     r[i][j] = g [i][j]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother with some ridiculous, arcane, illogical Microsoft format from the 80s. I would use ImageMagick to convert it to a PGM file (Portable Grey Map) which you will be able to read in in around 3 lines of C. The command to convert is `convert image.bmp image.pgm` Further info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *probably* due to sign extension on the `char` type. If you cast each byte to `unsigned char` it should work.

```
b[i][j] = (int)(0.11*(unsigned char)b[i][j] + 0.59*(unsigned char)g[i][j] + 0.3*(unsigned char)r[i][j]);
```

Edit: just noticed that the values are already `int`, so the sign extension has already occurred. In that case just mask it off.

```
b[i][j] = (int)(0.11*(0xff&b[i][j]) + 0.59*(0xff&g[i][j]) + 0.3*(0xff&r[i][j]));
```